# Change the Theme of Antd when using GatsbyJS

Tags: antd, gatsby

This GatsbyJS/antd plugin page (https://github.com/bskimball/gatsby-plugin-antd/issues/2) makes it seem that there is a way to edit ant.design (antd) themes when using GatsbyJS. The code that is provided is

```
plugins: [
  {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-antd',
      options: {
        style: true
      }
  }
]
```

But there is no additional information. Where would one make changes to things like the theme primary color (as described: https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme). The ant.design page (https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme) says to make the primary color change by doing the following:

```
"theme": {
  "primary-color": "#1DA57A",
},
```

It is not clear in what file such a variable would be set in GatbsyJS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GitHub repo with an example: https://github.com/uciska/gatsby-less-v2. To get Antd working changes must be made to three Gatsby files.

Example gastby-config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'My site'
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-less`,
      options: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        modifyVars: {
          'primary-color': '#da3043',
          'font-family': 'Arial',
          'layout-body-background': '#66ff79'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Example gastby-node.js:

```
exports.onCreateBabelConfig = ({ actions }) => {
  actions.setBabelPlugin({
    name: 'babel-plugin-import',
    options: {
      libraryName: 'antd',
      style: true
    }
  })
}
```

Example package.json:

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-hello-world",
  "description": "Gatsby hello world starter",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^3.6.4",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.8.0",
    "gatsby": "next",
    "gatsby-plugin-less": "next",
    "less": "^3.0.4",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-apollo": "^2.1.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: You do not need to edit gatsby-node if you are using gatsby-plugin-antd

Comment: @cannin Why do we need to include `less-loader`?  Doesn't `gatsby-plugin-less` add it for us?

Comment: @BrianKimball I used gatsby-plugin-antd, but still need to edit gatsby-node.js to take effect.

Answer (score 5):

I have tried all of the above answers which were written a few years back, but it didn't work. After researching for a couple of hours, finally, I was able to modify `antd` default vars with `gatsby`. Here is the solution:

`gatsby-config.js`

```
[
...
...
   {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-antd",
      options: {
        style: true,
      },
    },

    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-less",
      options: {
        lessOptions: {
          modifyVars: { //direct child node of lessOptions
            "primary-color": "#C53333", //your preferred color
          },
          javascriptEnabled: true, //direct child node of lessOptions
        },
      },
    },

]
```

`less` and `less-loader` are NOT required to modify default `antd` vars.

`package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
  "antd": "^4.12.2",
  "gatsby-plugin-antd": "^2.2.0",
  "gatsby-plugin-less": "^4.7.0",
}
```

side note: Find all the ant-design default vars [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.less)

Comment: I had to remove `@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';` from my top css file to avoid the less variables getting overwritten.

Answer (score 3):

This configuration worked for me.
I haven't added `babel-plugin-import` & haven't modified `gatsby-node.js` file.

Here is my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "web-master",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Become a fullstack developer",
  "version": "1.0",
  "author": "Vishal Shetty",
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^2.19.7",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.2.39",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.2.39",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.0.32",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.1.21",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.4.3",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.1.46",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.3.13",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "antd": "^3.26.12",
    "gatsby-plugin-antd": "^2.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-less": "^3.0.19",
    "less": "^3.11.1",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean"
  }
}
```

My `gatsby-config.js` file

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `WebMaster`,
    description: `Become a fullstack developer`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-antd",
      options: {
        style: true,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-less",
      options: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        modifyVars: {
          "primary-color": "#E4572E",
        },
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Look out for the plugins `gatsby-plugin-antd` and `gatsby-plugin-less` configuration.

That's it and it works.

Comment: I have tried this, it doesn't work in my case, do you have a codesandbox example of this solution?

Answer (score 2):

*Kudos to @cannin for his original answer. I have updated it with the latest lib name and reorg the text.*

To use ANTD with Gatsby and overwrite original styling

1. Add dependencies
   `yarn add babel-plugin-import less-loader antd gatsby-plugin-less`
2. Update Gatsby's setting:
   **gastby-config.js**
   add to the `plugins` array

   ```
   {
     resolve: `gatsby-plugin-less`,
     options: {
       javascriptEnabled: true,
       modifyVars: {
         'primary-color': '#663399',
         'font-family': 'Arial',
         'layout-body-background': '#66ff79'
       }
     },
   },
   ```

   **gastby-node.js**

   ```
   exports.onCreateBabelConfig = ({ actions }) => {
     actions.setBabelPlugin({
       name: 'babel-plugin-import',
       options: {
         libraryName: 'antd',
         style: true
       }
     })
   }
   ```
3. Example of using `antd` in component. This `primary` button shall display in Gatsby purple `#663399`

   ```
   import React from "react"
   import Layout from '../components/layout'
   import {Button} from 'antd'

   export default () => (
     <Layout>
       <div>
         <h1>ANTD</h1>
         <p>Such wow. Very React.</p>
         <Button type="primary">Button</Button>
       </div>
     </Layout>
   )
   ```

Comment: Why do you need to install less-loader?  Shouldn't less and gatsby-plugin-less be enough.

Comment: `javascriptEnabled` property should be in the `lessOptions`.