# Antd Theme is being overridden when used in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, antd

I am currently trying to customize Antd theme by using the antd and less plugins for Gatsby. Following this thread - [Change the Theme of Antd when using GatsbyJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831582/change-the-theme-of-antd-when-using-gatsbyjs)

gatsby-config.js plugins contain

```
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-antd',
      options: {
        style: true
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-less`,
      options: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        modifyVars: {
          'primary-color': '#BADA55'
        }
      }
    }
```

gatsby-node.js and relevant modules are filled as seen in the thread.

When I look at an element in the browser debugger, the button uses the base theme, but the specified theme is actually there (just being overridden).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and for me it was that I had somewhere in my code imported the style for antd

`import "antd/dist/antd.css"`